# manipulate html before append to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = '<div><span></span><div id="container"><span>one</span><span class="target"></span></div></div>';
  console.log($(x).find('#container').get(0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am able to get the container block but how to remove the `.target span`?

Comment: their is not need to remove element after creating html. Just create those html that you want to append.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking to remove the entire element if the `class` matches `.target`?
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $('<div><span></span><div id="container"><span>one</span><span class="target"></span></div></div>');
    x.find('.target').get(0).remove();
    console.log(x.html());
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/na14yvmb/).

---

**Edit**

As `x.html()` strips off the root element (i.e. the `<div></div>`), here is the solution if you would like to get the full HTML string.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $('<div><span></span><div id="container"><span>one</span><span class="target"></span></div></div>');
    x.find('.target').get(0).remove();
    x = x.wrap('<div>').parent().html();
    console.log(x);
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/na14yvmb/2/).

---

**Edit 2**

In the case where there are more than one `.target`, say for example the following string:

`<div><span></span><div id="container"><span>one</span><span class="target"></span><span class="target"></span><i class="target"></i></div></div>`

You can consider removing `get(0)`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $('<div><span></span><div id="container"><span>one</span><span class="target"></span><span class="target"></span><i class="target"></i></div></div>');
    x.find('.target').remove();
    x = x.wrap('<div>').parent().html();
    console.log(x);
});
```

Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/na14yvmb/3/) again.

Comment: what if I have more than 1 target class? get(0) doesn't work.

Comment: @Jennifer updated the fiddle with the example, do take a look! Removing `get(0)` in this context will remove all elements with `.target`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(x).find(".target").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

$(x).find("span.target");

Answer (score 0):

See below.

**FYI** -- there is no span inside element with class of target... so doing '.target span' kinda makes no sense

```
var x = '<div><span></span><div id="container"><span>one</span><span class="target"></span></div></div>';

var elem = $(x).find("#container").parent();
elem.find('.target').remove();
```

Comment: why do u need parent() in this case?

Comment: u don't but.... was trying to illiterate how you would get the beginning... as the selector you specified doesn't exist so thought it  would probably help... at least this way your at the root. your could of done the selector on the first div.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var x = '<div><span></span><div id="container"><span>one</span><span class="target"></span></div></div>';

var elem = $(x).find("#container").parent();
elem.find('.target').remove();
var div = $('<div>').append(elem).html();
console.log(div);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8dh3bze7/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var x = '<div><span></span><div id="container"><span>one</span><span id="target">ssss</span></div></div>';
  var y = $(x).find("#target").remove().text();
  //$(x).find(".target").remove();

    $('#new').append( "<p>Test</p>" + y);
});
```